Importing modules with path alias not working
I have a project that is structured in this way:
src/
src/common/components/
src/common/constants/
src/common/hooks/

I am using webpack as a build tool and typescript. I have tried to setup a path alias for common directory first with webpack by adding alias property to resolve in config:
import { fileURLToPath } from "node:url";

import { CleanWebpackPlugin } from "clean-webpack-plugin";
import { EsbuildPlugin } from "esbuild-loader";
import MiniCssExtractPlugin from "mini-css-extract-plugin";
import path from "path";
import rehypeSlug from "rehype-slug";
import webpack from "webpack";

import deps from "./package.json" assert { type: "json" };

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);
const { ModuleFederationPlugin } = webpack.container;
export default {
    entry: "./src/index.tsx",
    output: {
        filename: "[name].[fullhash].js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./dist"),
    },
    experiments: {
        topLevelAwait: true,
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js", ".jsx"],
        alias: {
            Common: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/common"),
        }
    },

But, when I import something from common directory like that:
import text from "Common/constants/texts";

I get an error:
Cannot find module 'Common/constants/texts' at webpackMissingModule

I have also tried to configure it with typescript instead by adding baseUrl and paths properties to compilerOptions:
"baseUrl": "src",
"paths": {
  "@common/*": ["src/common/*"],
}

But, that didn't work either. What am I doing wrong here?

Try -> "baseUrl": "./src"   , and then import text from "@common/......

I tried it, but it still doesn't work @Keith
